# Is it possible to use both an external css stylesheet / js file and an external svg file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to use external css / js files in altering an external svg file, however, upon "importing" the svg file into the html, its "subtags" such as path are not imported, and therefore the css and js cannot alter it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <object data="map.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
                <script src="map.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have seen multiple proposed solutions that I do not see functioning. If anyone could explain these or propose their own I would be thankful.

- Inline svg [My map file has over 3000 lines of code, and would be difficult to read the html]
- Have a seperate stylesheet for map.svg [I can't seem to have this work]
- Have inline css for map.svg [I would like if the files could be separated and I don't see the equivalent for js]
- Have a javascript injection [I can't seem to have this work, and I believe this just uses a javascript file to dynamically add the path elements from the svg file, I would be willing to have a separate js file or incorporate it into my html js file, and prefer this method]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you "importing" the SVG file into html? How are you "having a separate stylsheet", please include a [mcve] of the non-working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SVG has the [same host as a document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#concept-bcc-content-document) you can use [getSVGDocument](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content-other.html#dom-media-getsvgdocument) to get SVG document from JavaScript

```html
    <object id="map" data="js.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
    <script>
      const mapObject = document.getElementById("map");
      mapObject.addEventListener("load", () => {
        mapObject
          .getSVGDocument()
          .querySelector("path")
          .setAttribute("fill", "red");
      });
    </script>
```